# How to add SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1 OR SP2 to prerequisites window in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce

My application depends on Compact Server "SP1" but when I attempt to add this from the prerequisites window in the deployment project of my application it only shows "SQL Server Compact 3.5" that leads to an installation of older version and not SP1 upon deployment.

How can I get Visual Studio 2008 to update its prerequisites list to include SP1? or even SP2 or SQL Compact 4.0?

Note that I have ensured that SP1 is already installed in the development machine.
I cannot upgrade to VS 2010 due to certain dependencies.

Comment: SQL Server Compact is on NuGet, wouldn't it be better to just bundle the correct library with your application?

Comment: That is not what I am trying to do actually... I am trying to make sure that the system in which I am deploying my application in has SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1 installed in it before I install my application. Therefore, requiring a pre-req....

Comment: My point is, if you bundle the library with your application, you don't really need it to be installed up front. Your app will just use its private copy at the correct version. (Which is a major advantage of using an embedded DB to begin with.)

Comment: I could do that but I dont want to do a private deployment because I'd like to have the latest updates from MS.

Comment: In that case you don't really need to install the latest version during deployment, just let it get updated by the OS. (Assuming SQL Server CE gets OS updates; if it doesn't, the whole point is moot anyway.)

Comment: Sure... but my installation wizard needs to make sure that it exists before MS can update it. To do that, SP1 atleast needs to be installed before app deployment...

Comment: My installation depends on SP1 not just my application if that makes more sense..